# I can see requests is installed but ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

Tags: python, pip, conda

I can see `requests` is installed in my conda environment. When I type `conda list` there is `requests` at the list.

```
qtconsole                 5.3.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
qtpy                      2.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
readline                  8.1.2                h7f8727e_1
regex                     2022.6.2                 pypi_0    pypi
requests                  2.28.0                   pypi_0    pypi
responses                 0.18.0                   pypi_0    pypi
rouge-score               0.0.4                    pypi_0    pypi
send2trash                1.8.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
```

but when I go into python and try to `import requests` it doesn't work.

```
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

What should I do? I'm definitely in my conda environment.

```
(env1) june@vgpu1:~$
```

Comment: What is the output of `which python`?

Comment: @Saddy `/home/june/conda/envs/env1/bin/python`

Comment: better check `python -m pip list`